# How to add parent_item_id to Magento Soap API response?

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, soap-api-v2

I need to pull the parent_item_id for order items when calling salesOrderInfo() in soap.

I made below changes to wsdl.xml and wsi.xml under `salesOrderItemEntity` in Mage/Sales/etc/.

### Wsdl.xml

> `<element name="parent_item_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />`

### Wsi.xml

> `<xsd:element name="parent_item_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />`

Also I have cleared the magento cache and wsdl cache in /tmp

Any help would be appreciated.